# How to pass parameter in from clause of query in sp?

Tags: sql

```
Select * from table1 where name = 'sam'
```

Here `name = 'sam'` it is static part. Dynamic part is tablename. How can I pass tablename to sp 
as input para.

```
Create Procedure Proc_sp1
(
 @table varchar(10)
)
as
 Select * from @table where name = 'sam'
```

I know, need to use `sp_executesqland` use `'+@table+'` in query . Is there any option other than `sp_executesql`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific set of tables, you can pass parameter and use "if-else" conditions, which table will be used for the select:

pseudo:

```
IF @TableName = 'TableA'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ....
END
ELSE IF @TableName = 'TableB'
BEIN
    SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ....
END
```